# How to perform delta-import in solr with authentication?

Tags: shell, curl, solr

I have completed solr full import, now I have to automate delta-import using linux-cron. This is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/dataimport?command=delta-import
```

The solr in my server is protected with authentication. so how to authenticate and then do delta-import using curl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the standard HTTP syntax [for basic authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters):

```
curl http://user:pass@localhost:8983/solr/..
```

Comment: Full query is curl http:/user:pass@/localhost:8983/solr/<core_name>/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false&commit=true